# Web login usage with Perl and CGI

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, perl, cgi

I have to do a website with `.cgi` files, so i have my index.cgi :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI qw/:standard/;
use HTML::Template;
use CGI::Session;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
require "cgi-bin/web_base.pl";

my $q = CGI->new();
my $s = CGI::Session->new($q);

print header();

print my_topbar();

print login_form();
print footer();
```

> "web_base.pl"  contains functions who print html code

evrything is displaying corectly etc.. but i don't understand anything about login form :/

here is my login form input :

```
<div class="container" align=center>
    <form id="form_id" method="post" name="myform">
        <font color="white">
            <label>Username :</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-small" name="username" id="username"/>
            <br>
            <label>Password :</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-small" name="password" id="password"/>
            <br>
            <input type="button" class="form-small btn btn-default" value="Login" id="submit" onclick="validate()"/>
        </font>
    </form>
```

and my JS login script (he is include in header) :

```
function validate(){
var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
if ( username == "moomoo" && password == "foobar"){
alert ("Login successfully");
window.location = "success.cgi"; // Redirecting to other page.
return false;
}
else
{
alert("Error: Invalid username or password. Try again or contact support.");
return false;
}
}
```

So, my question is, how can i make my website verify if user is logged on every page ? and change few things like display disconnect button etc...

I hope someone nice is going to help me <3 i'm on this since 1 week ago :')

Comment: `<font color="white">` that's no valid HTML, there's not `<font>` tag.

Comment: @Roberrrt that is not what i asked, but it's working this way.

Comment: That might be 'working' this way, but that's no way the reason why your font color is white. You can remove the `<font></font>` entirely.

Comment: so what is the good way you think ? @Roberrrt

Comment: @Roberrrt with clear-text passwords in the JS and `require`d .pl files that print HTML that's probably the least of the OP's problems. @superzero10 if this is something you inherited, it's time to rewrite it from scratch. It can probably be done in a few lines using a modern framework like [Mojolicious](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious) or [Dancer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer) but you should probably read a few of their guides and then ask a more specific question -- with code like the above I don't even know where to start.

Comment: since someone could 'view source' in browser and get the login details this is offering you zero security. Anyone can see these details and where the redirect goes.

Comment: @mbethke the only thing i didn't do is the login.js script, everything else is from me and i'm on it since 2 weeks ago so i don't really want to rewrite it from scratch ^^'

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche so what is the best way for good security and not really difficult to make ? ^^'

Comment: @superzero10 nothing is being passed to your perl script, there's nothing to stop anyone from accessing success.cgi. There may as well be no login form

Comment: @superzero10 It seems you don't understand CGI, HTTP or JavaScript well enough. Take the advice of a modern framework, Dancer or Mojolicious. Learn the basics of one. The 'best way' is to validate logins server side without having the credentials hard coded for in the webpage for the world to see.

Comment: @Roberrrt since the OP did not specify which version of HTML they are using, it is very valid. E.g. in [HTML 3.2 the `<font>` tag was still included](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32.html#font). Don't assume everything is HTML 5. Old applications are old.

Comment: @simbabque I herby apologize. You have taught me a valuable lesson today. (https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Wilbur/pr7may96.html) 1996, damn

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche so if i understand, everything i done is useless and i have to restart it all with dancer or mojo ? wich one is the most simple ?

Comment: @superzero10 that's only your server side. As it is your client and server side are both wrong. there is nothing in success.cgi to stop anyone from viewing it. How do you expect this to work? You need to learn basic HTTP first

Comment: @Roberrrt and a bright future! My rule is that if it has CGI then it doesn't comply to anything. ;-) Also the code in question does not have `use strict` or `use warnings` and has `FatalsToBrowser` in it. All of those are good indications that it's very old.

Comment: In regards to restarting this with a modern web framework, can you tell us a bit more background? Is this a personal project, is it for paid work, or for school? Do you have the authority to just change everything and start from scratch? Is it going to run somewhere where you can decide what kind of program will be run there? All of those need to be taken into account before making such a decision. Dancer has a very low learning curve for simple things and is likely a good approach, but you need to know if you will be able to use it in your specific setting.

Comment: @simbabque no, the page `success.cgi` can be seen in the JavaScript redirect, nothing is passed to it to validate a login. Anyone could type this into the URL bar and get there, without having to type in the hardcoded plain text login details also in the JavaScript

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche yes, I reread your comment and then understood what you mean. Sorry about that. I agree.

Comment: I believe [this lightning talk](https://youtu.be/jKOqtRMT85s) by Sawyer X is very relevant and highly entertaining.

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche sorry i was not at work.
so, my project is to do a dashboard web with login, who display statuts of many servers. It's for paid work, for my traineeship. the server use index.cgi first. my boss ask for perl usage for server request at least

Comment: In that case, using a modern web framework might not be the best approach. Your boss might not like that. I suggest you look at existing code. There are probably a bunch of programs that already do what you want. Read code, and also read the version control history. It will tell you a lot about how work is being done in your company. On the other hand, if your company is fine with using new stuff, go for a Dancer2 application.

Comment: @simbabque can i use Dancer '1' ? he is already install on my server and it might be difficult to install Dancer2..
and, when i try to run app.pl, he says : bind to 0.0.0.0:3000: Address already in use at... /Dancer.pm

Comment: Sure. Dancer is fine. There is one running on port 3000. That is good because it shows it will work. You need to use a different port though. That should be `-p 4444` or something like that. The port is where the server is going to listen.

Comment: I can't search right now as I am on my phone. Go to metacpan.org and look for the Dancer tutorial. Or go to irc.perl.org and join # dancer. People there will explain. :-)

Comment: @simbabque so, i want to put dancer on the port 1080, where my website is supposed to be, but same problem. then, i tried random port : 1090, 1081, 2000... and when i sucess to "enter the dancefloor" i can't access the page. i think this might come from my server, but it's a huge server with many stuff on it so i don't want to mess with it...

Comment: and the fact that Dancer needs to be run 24/7 to access the website is weird

Comment: You need to understand how the whole thing works. Maybe read the Plack documentation. Dancer is running through PSGI, not CGI. For a CGI script, there is a webserver like Apache 2. For PSGI/Plack, there is not. It brings its own tiny server. You will need to _deploy_ it, and it will then run itself. You run the `bin/app.pl` manually only during development. When you pick your port, let's say you do `perl bin/app.pl -p 1090`, then it will listen on that port. So on the same machine, you go to http://localhost:1090/ to access it. Read up on PSGI/Plack on CPAN, it's very easy once you understand

Answer (score 0):

First your method is very insecure.

I found this link that should put you on the right track, it does not `use HTML::Template;` but you can add that in for your code. 
[login and logout of sessions in 2 cgi scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991156/login-and-logout-of-sessions-in-2-cgi-scripts)